# How to approach this minimum lambda problem?

Tags: optimization, plane-geometry

> The problem is this: If the smallest positive number $\lambda$, such that for any $17$ points on the plane $P_{1}, P_{2}, \ldots, P_{17}($ can overlap too), if the distance between any two of them does not exceed 1 , then $$\sum_{1 \leq i<j \leq 17}\left|P_{i} P_{j}\right|^{2} \leq \lambda \space \text{find this} \space \lambda$$

i have literally no clue how to optimize lambda the best possible, i can just think of large numbers which can be quite significant but not enough close to lamda minimum we want in the problem.

Comment: what is $P_iP_j$ when $P_i,P_j$ are points in the plane? Do you mean $P_i \cdot P_j$?

Comment: also what do you mean that the points can overlap? That $P_1 = P_2$, for example?

Comment: PiPj is distance between those points Pi and Pj and yes  P1 may be equal to P2  , and all these r points in a plane

Comment: So it sounds like you are looking to maximize the sum of squares of pairwise distances between the points in your set. So each arrangement of points provides a lower bound. What happens when they are in a line? In a circle? Can you play with some arrangements and build up intuition about what arrangement should be used for maximal distance?

Comment: I at first tried straight line /circle only but in both configurations i cant able to maintain the distance between some points sooner or later less than 1 (After fixing some points then thinking of next point then this catch happens)

Comment: You shouldn't be far from the good $\lambda$ if points $P_i$ are taken as the vertices of the $17$-vertex **star-shaped** regular polygon inscribed in a circle with radius $1/2$ obtained by joining points $P_i$ to points $P_{i+8}$ (mod 17)...

Comment: Gud , How to prove that that is the best strategy @Jean Marie ? For min lambda ?

Comment: I have made my comment more precise.  I have no good answer at present to the comment you just made...

Comment: Yeah but ur idea is gud i will work on it and tell what i got

Comment: Now i logically think that ur is the best bound possible , i dont get a decent proof of that polygon case though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint:

Let us consider, in a first step, the   extreme situation where the $A_k$s are the vertices of a regular polygon with $n=17$ vertices inscribed in a circle with radius $r=1/2$ (see figure).

This polygon, called a *heptadecagon*, is famous because it has attracted the attention of Gauss for reasons explained [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Heptadecagon.html).

In the case this configuration is optimal, we would have, for the sum of the squares of all mutual distances:

$$\lambda_{opt}=(nr)^2= (17/2)^2=\frac{289}{4}\tag{1}$$

This formula comes from a known formula $n^2$ for the sum of the squares of the lengths of all diagonals (including the sides) in any regular polygon with $n$ vertices inscribed in the **unit** circle : see formula 1 page 2 in this [document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.06971.pdf).

In a second step, we have to slightly rectify our first guess. Indeed, the longest diagonal $A_1A_{9}$ of the heptadecagon with radius $1/2$ being equal to

$$a = \sin(8\pi/17)\approx 0.995734176295034$$

one shouldn't take  $r=1/2$ in (1) but $r=1/(2a)$ for reaching the optimal (?) situation, once again without proof that the optimal $\lambda$ is obtained in this way.

[image]

Comment: Thanks it makes sense , but as i dont have offical answer to this problem yet nor the best bound proof , i dont know if i should  tick it or not , but i am satisified so i will upvote it for now is it gud @JeanMarie?

Comment: That's fine. I still look for a proof of optimality.

Comment: while searching for a bit i saw this , does this give a better way to get the best bound, if u want u can maybe modify the sol of yours i will tick it then @JeanMarie https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1214690p6037755

Comment: I have had a look at the artofproblemsolving reference you gave. Then I have made matlab simulations by grouping 4 by 4 +1 then 5 by 5 + 2 the vertices (in order to have either a square or an equilateral triangle): this always generates a sum that is (**very slightly**) under the $\lambda_{opt}$ I gave... I think this is due to the fact that $n=17$ is prime (which is not the case for $12$). But, once again, these simulations are by no means an optimality proof...

Comment: I understand @jeanmarie but then just for 12 case isnt the lamda from ur method would be (12/2)^2 <48?

Comment: Yes, but I insist on the fact that $17$ is a rather different kind of number compared to $12$ because $12$ can yield to neat groupings of points : 3 groups of 4 points or 4 groups of 3 points, whereas $17=4*4+1$ or $17=3*5+2$. Therefore, nothing surprizing that the $\lambda_{opt}$ is not obtained in the same way...

Comment: Hmm gud observation , i will then tick it as it mostly solves the problem , thanks for your answer